# MPDF Checkbox not showing in PDF only dot

Tags: php, html, checkbox, mpdf

Im using MPDF to output my html form into a PDF. But my problem is, when it converts to PDF the box shape of checkbox is gone, below is the sample how i coded the checkbox

```
<input type='checkbox' name='opening' value='referal' checked="checked"> Check 1
<input type='checkbox' name='opening' value='referal2' checked="checked"> Check 2
```

Here's  the html output before converting:
[Here's  the html output before converting:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZ9j6.png)

Here's the mpdf OUTPUT:
[Here's the mpdf output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2ra3.png)

As you can see, the check '✓' became dot '.' and the box shape is gone.
Is there something wrong with my code? Or It is just not possible with MPDF?

But let me add, if I'm using radio button, all is fine. But what I need is checkbox not radio button.
Radio Button OUTPUT:[Radio Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zK3RN.png)

Heres my full code GeneratePDF.php

```
<?php

include('mpdf60/mpdf.php');


$html .=

 "  


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Applicant Information Sheet</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.css'>
</head>
<body>
<div class=' header-logos text-center'>
    <img src='headerimage/logo1.png' width='270' height='90' class=''>
    <img src='headerimage/logo2.png' width='170' height='130' class='' >
    <img src='headerimage/logo3.png' width='180' height='90' class=''>
</div>
<div class='container top-head'>
    <p class='form-hrm'>FORM-HRM-R-003</p>
    <hr>
    <div class='col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12'>
    <div class='profile-pic'></div>
    <p class='blackened-head'>APPLICANTS INFORMATION SHEET</p>
        <form class='head-form'>
            <span class='detail1'>Date</span><span class='user-texts'>:</span><span class='user-texts bold'> Nicky Jacobo</span><br>
            <span class='detail2'>Position</span><span class='user-texts'>:</span> <span class='choice1 '>1st choice</span><span class='user-texts'>:</span> <span class='user-texts bold'>Information Technology</span><span class='choice2'> 2nd choice</span><span class='user-texts'>: </span><span class='user-texts bold'>Hotel Management</span><br>
            <span class='detail3'>Salary Expectation</span><span class='user-texts'>:</span><span class='user-texts bold'>100,000</span><br>
            <span class='detail4'>Availability to Start</span><span class='user-texts'>: </span><span class='user-texts bold'>Anytime</span><br>

        </form>
    <p class='blackened peros'>PERSONAL INFORMATION</p>

    </div>  

</div><!-- End of top-head -->

<!--==========================================
PERSONAL INFORMATION
============================================= -->
<div class='container personal-information'>
    <table>
      <tr class='zero-row'>
        <th colspan='6' >NAME: <span class='outs'>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <span class='lastname ' style='font-weight: 900;'>JACOBO</span>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

            <span class='firstname' style='font-weight: 900;'>NICKY</span>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <span class='midname' style='font-weight: 800;'>CABALU</span> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><br>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;


            <span class='lastnamedet'>(last name)</span>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <span class='firstnamedet'>(first name)</span>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <span  class='midnamedet'>(middle name)</span>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr class='first-row'>
        <td>NICKNAME<br><span class='user-texts bold'>Nicks</span></td>
        <td>BIRTHDATE (mm/dd/yyyy)<br><span class='user-texts bold'>10/25/1994</span></td>
        <td>BIRTHPLACE<br><span class='user-texts bold'>Tokyo Japan</span></td>
        <td>AGE<br><span class='user-texts bold'>18</span></td>
        <td>HEIGHT<br><span class='user-texts bold'>5'7'</span></td>
        <td>WEIGHT<br><span class='user-texts bold'>60kg</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class='second-row'>
        <td  colspan='6'>CITY ADDRESS: <span class='bold'>Plaridel Bulacan</span> </td>
      </tr>
       <tr class='third-row'>
        <td  colspan='6'>PROVINCIAL ADDRESS: <span  class='bold'>Plaridel Bulacan</span> </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class='fourth-row'>
        <td rowspan='2' ><span class='residentstatus'>RESIDENTIAL STATUS:</span>
        <form>
            <input type='checkbox' name='gender' value='own' checked='checked'> &nbsp;Own House<br>
            <input type='checkbox' name='gender' value='rent'> &nbsp;Rent<br>
            <input type='checkbox' name='gender' value='other' > &nbsp;Others (specify): <span class='bold'>Own Mansion</span>
        </form> 
      </td>
        <td rowspan='2'><span class='gender'>GENDER:</span>
        <form>
        <input type='checkbox' name='gender' value='male' checked='checked'> &nbsp;Male<br>
        <input type='checkbox' name='gender' value='female' > &nbsp;Female<br>
        </form>
        </td>
        <td colspan='2'>
        MOBILE TEL. #: <span  class='bold outs'>0926-107-4423</span><br><br>
        RESIDENCE  TEL. #:  <span  class='bold outs'>02-25429</span>

      </td>
        <td colspan='2' >EMAIL ADDRESS:<br><span  class='bold outs'>yinkciworks@gmail.com</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class='fifth-row'>
        <td colspan='4'>CIVIL STATUS:<br>
            <input type='checkbox' name='civil-stat' value='single' checked='checked'> &nbsp;Single&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input type='checkbox' name='civil-stat' value='married' > &nbsp;Married&nbsp;
            <input type='checkbox' name='civil-stat' value='single-parent' > &nbsp;Single Parent&nbsp;
            <input type='checkbox' name='civil-stat' value='widow' > &nbsp;Widow&nbsp;
            <input type='checkbox' name='civil-stat' value='other-status'> &nbsp;Others: 
            <span  class='bold'>Complicated</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
        <tr class='sixth-row'>
            <td colspan='2' rowspan='2'>Nationality<br><br>
            <input type='checkbox' name='filipino' value='filipino' checked='checked'> &nbsp;Filipino<br>
            <input type='checkbox' name='othersnationalit' value='female' > &nbsp;Others (specify): 
            <span  class='bold outs'>Alien Gender</span>
            </td>
            <td colspan='4'>SSS:
                <span  class='bold'>29-7098-7685-456</span>
&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;
                TIN:
                <span  class='bold'>29-7098-7685-456</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class='seventh-row'>
        <td colspan='4'>CURRENT ACTIVITIES:
            <span  class='bold'>Nandemonai</span>
        </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<!--==========================================
EMPLOYMENT HISTORY
============================================= -->
    <p class='blackened'>EMPLOYMENT HISTORY</p>
    <table class='table-two'>
        <tr>
        <th>COMPANY NAME</th>
        <th>LAST POSITION</th>
        <th>IMMEDIATE SUPERIOR</th>
        <th>CONTACT NUMBER</th>
        <th>INCLUSIVE DATES</th>
        <th>REASON FOR LEAVING</th>
        <th>SALARY</th>
        </tr>

        <tr class='table2-first-row'>
        <td><span  class='bold'>iConcept Global</span></td>
        <td><span  class='bold'>Web Developer</span></td>
        <td><span  class='bold'>Supervisor</span></td>
        <td><span  class='bold'>0926-107-4423</span></td>
        <td><span  class='bold'>Oct 25 1994</span></td>
        <td><span  class='bold'>Mayaman na</span></td>
        <td><span  class='bold'>100,000</span></td>
        </tr>

        <tr class='table2-first-row'>
        <td><span  class='bold'>iConcept Global</span></td>
        <td><span  class='bold'>Web Developer</span></td>
        <td><span  class='bold'>Supervisor</span></td>
        <td><span  class='bold'>0926-107-4423</span></td>
        <td><span  class='bold'>Oct 25 1994</span></td>
        <td><span  class='bold'>Mayaman na</span></td>
        <td><span  class='bold'>100,000</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class='table2-first-row'>
        <td><span  class='bold'>iConcept Global</span></td>
        <td><span  class='bold'>Web Developer</span></td>
        <td><span  class='bold'>Supervisor</span></td>
        <td><span  class='bold'>0926-107-4423</span></td>
        <td><span  class='bold'>Oct 25 1994</span></td>
        <td><span  class='bold'>Mayaman na</span></td>
        <td><span  class='bold'>100,000</span></td>
        </tr>

        <tr class='table2-first-row'>
        <td><span  class='bold'>iConcept Global</span></td>
        <td><span  class='bold'>Web Developer</span></td>
        <td><span  class='bold'>Supervisor</span></td>
        <td><span  class='bold'>0926-107-4423</span></td>
        <td><span  class='bold'>Oct 25 1994</span></td>
        <td><span  class='bold'>Mayaman na</span></td>
        <td><span  class='bold'>100,000</span></td>
        </tr>   
    </table>
<!--==========================================
FAMILY BACKGROUND
============================================= -->
<p class='blackened'>FAMILY BACKGROUND</p>
<table class='table-three'>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>NAME</th>
            <th>AGE</th>
            <th>OCCUPATION</th>
            <th>COMPANY/SCHOOL</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Father</td>
            <td><span   class='bold'>Nicky Jacobo</span></td>
            <td><span   class='bold'>18</span></td>
            <td><span   class='bold'>Web Developer</span></td>
            <td><span   class='bold'>Secret</span></td>
        </tr>   
        <tr>
            <td>Mother</td>
            <td><span   class='bold'>Nicky Jacobo</span></td>
            <td><span   class='bold'>18</span></td>
            <td><span   class='bold'>Web Developer</span></td>
            <td><span   class='bold'>Secret</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan='4'>Brothers &amp; Siters</td>
            <td><span class='bold'>Nicky Jacobo</span></td>
            <td><span class='bold'>18</span></td>
            <td><span class='bold'>Web Developer</span></td>
            <td><span class='bold'>Secret</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span class='bold'>Nicky Jacobo</span></td>
            <td><span class='bold'>18</span></td>
            <td><span class='bold'>Web Developer</span></td>
            <td><span class='bold'>Secret</span></td>   
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span class='bold'>Nicky Jacobo</span></td>
            <td><span class='bold'>18</span></td>
            <td><span class='bold'>Web Developer</span></td>
            <td><span class='bold'>Secret</span></td>   
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span class='bold'>Nicky Jacobo</span></td>
            <td><span class='bold'>18</span></td>
            <td><span class='bold'>Web Developer</span></td>
            <td><span class='bold'>Secret</span></td>           
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Spouse</td>
            <td><span class='bold'>Not available</span></td>
            <td><span class='bold'>18</span></td>
            <td><span class='bold'>Web Developer</span></td>
            <td><span class='bold'>Secret</span></td>   
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Children</td>
            <td><span class='bold'>Not available</span></td>
            <td><span class='bold'>18</span></td>
            <td><span class='bold'>Web Developer</span></td>
            <td><span class='bold'>Secret</span></td>   
        </tr>
</table>
<!--==========================================
REFERENCES
============================================= -->
<p class='blackened'>REFERENCES</p>
<table class='table-four'>
        <tr>
            <th>NAME</th>
            <th>POSITION</th>
            <th>COMPANY</th>
            <th>ADDRESS</th>
            <th>CONTACT NO.</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span class='bold centerme'>Shana Hirai</span></td>
            <td><span class='bold centerme'>Flame Haze</span></td>
            <td><span class='bold centerme'>Shakugan no Shana</span></td>
            <td><span class='bold centerme'>Anime</span></td>
            <td><span class='bold centerme'>0926-107-4423</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan='9' colspan='3' class='etu'>How did you know of the opening?<br>
            <input type='checkbox' name='opening' value='news' checked> &nbsp;Newspaper Ad  &nbsp; &nbsp; <br>
            <input type='checkbox' name='opening' value='school'> &nbsp;School Placement  &nbsp; &nbsp;<br>
            <input type='checkbox' name='opening' value='walkin'> &nbsp;Walk-in<br>
            <input type='checkbox' name='opening' value='referal' checked> &nbsp;Referral of: <span class='bold outs'>Friend</span> <br>

            <input type='checkbox' name='opening' value='other-ads' checked> &nbsp;Others (specify): <span class='bold outs'>Facebook Ads</span><br><br>

            </td>
            <td  rowspan='9' colspan='2'>
                <span class='emergency italic'>In case of emergency please contact:</span><br>
                Name: <span class='bold'> Sakai Yuji</span><br>
                Contact No.: <span class='bold'>0926-107-4423</span><br>
                Relation to you: <span class='bold'>Tomodachi</span><br><br>
            </td>
        </tr>


</table>
<p class='ihereby'>I hereby certify that the above information is true and correct and I hereby authorize Cabalen to verify the said information.</p>
<table class='last-part'>
    <tr>
        <th><span class=''>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;signed already</span><br><br>
        <span class='sign-details'>&emsp;Applicant&#39;s Signature</span></th>
        <th><span class=''>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;Oct 23 2017</span><br><br>
        <span class='date-details'>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;Date</span></th>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>


";


$mpdf=new mPDF('utf-8', 'Letter', 0, '', 2, 2, 12, 2, 2, 2);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
 $mpdf->shrink_tables_to_fit = 1;
$mpdf->Output();

?>
```

Comment: I am also getting above issues in mpdf print but I got out like checked means  '✓' unchecked checkbox means nothing showing. Below attribute extra used mpdf.
 
$mpdf->useActiveForms = true; I need box shape for unchecked checkbox.

Answer (score 3):

**The mPDF docs state that the first argument of `Output()` is the file path, second is the saving mode - you need to set it to 'F'.**

```
$mpdf->Output('filename.pdf','F'); //Only save to File
```

Updated: You may need this too:

```
$mpdf->Output('filename.pdf','D');
```

Answer (score 3):

I already found the cause, its the maxcdn bootstrap link, I only removed the link then everything went fine.

Comment: Is there any other way that with using bootstrap css, you achieved the same?